# Is there a Qutip equivalent of "expand_operator" for superoperators?

Tags: programming, quantum-operation, qutip

I want to calculate a superoperator for a small noisy subsystem consisting of $k$ qubits, and expand it to $n > k$ qubits, where the remaining $n-k$ qubits are not subject to any noise. `Expand_operator` only works for `oper`-types, and there is no `expand_superoperator` type of functionality in Qutip. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Can you do `expand_operator` for the `oper`-type, and then do `to_super` on that? So just do everything in `oper` land, and then when you're ready go to `superop` land.

Comment: I found the solution! It's a bit tricky, but converting to `oper`-type won't work: that won't take into account the internal structure of a `super`-type. `super_tensor` works, with the `permute` function that `expand_operator` uses.

Comment: Nice! Glad you found the solution.